# How to redirect .php to .html using .htaccess

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, redirect

I uploaded my code on testing server and link is below

http://dynamicwebsite.co.in/kk/ksmotors/tafe/aboutus.html

Now I want when someone hit below URL then user redirect to above URL

http://dynamicwebsite.co.in/kk/ksmotors/tafe/index.php?page=aboutus.php

I used following .htaccess code but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteRule ^index.php?page=(.*).php/?$ $1/$2.html$3 [R=301,L]
#RedirectMatch 301 /form/5/.* www.example.com/form/12/name.html

RedirectMatch 301 /index.php?page=aboutus.php http://dynamicwebsite.co.in/kk/ksmotors/tafe/aboutus.html

#Disable php and html files in storage folders
RedirectMatch 403 (admin\/accessory\/images|admin\/careers\/images|admin\/categories\/images|admin\/css|admin\/images|admin\/jqgrid|admin\/models\/images|admin\/submodels\/images|css|images|js|php-captcha|resume|spec_doc).+\.(php|php3?|phtml|html)$

#Disable Directory Listing
Options -Indexes
```

can you please explain what is going wrong.
Please help.
Thanks

Comment: I already tried this but not working. I have no more idea about .htaccess

Comment: See this : https://helponnet.com/2021/04/27/how-to-convert-php-extension-into-html-using-rewriterule-in-htaccess/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L]
```

Rewriting a URL

This example rewrites a URL to another URL. This rewrites example.com/1.html to example.com/abc.php?id=1

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+).html /abc.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Refer [link](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Comment: not working look http://dynamicwebsite.co.in/kk/ksmotors/tafe/index.php?page=aboutus.php

Comment: okay i will update code

Answer (score 1):

you can add this in your .htaccsess file if you want to redirect to html from php. add your **pagename** in code.

```html
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase / RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.+)\.php 
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [L,R=301] 
RewriteRule ^pagename\.html$ pagename.php [T=application/x-httpd-php,L] 
RewriteEngine on 
rewritecond %{http_host} ^xyz.org [nc] 
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://xyz./$1 [r=301,nc] 
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [NC,R,L] 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```